# DB Architecture : Linking to intersection or to main tables?

Tags: database, data-structures, architecture

I'm creating fantasy football system on my website but i'm very confuse about how I should link some of my table.

**Tables**

The main table is `Pool` which have all the info about the ruling of the fantasy draft.

A standard table `User`, which contains the usual stuff.

Intersection table called `pools_users` which contains `id,pool_id,user_id` because a user could be in more than one pool, and a pool contains more than 1 user.

**The problem**

Table `Selections` => that's the table that is causing problem. That's the selection that the user choose for his pool. This is related to the `Player` table but thats not relevant for this problem.

Should I link this table to the table Pools_users or should I link it with both main table Pool and User. This table contains `id,pool_id,user_id,player_id,...`

What is the best way link my tables? When I want to retrieve my data, I normally want the information to be divided BY users. "This user have those selections, this one those selections, etc).

Answer (score 1):

What is a Pool?  Is it a League, that is, a group of teams competing against each other?  The reason I ask is because it seems like you have a entity missing, to wit, Team**(*)**.

To a certain extent this decision depends on the rules of the fantasy football game you are running, but in my experience most games allow Users to participate in multiple Leagues (?Pools?) but to manage just the one Team.  So there is a one to one relationship between Users and Teams.  Once we look at it this way it becomes clear that Selections must be an intersection table between Teams (Users) and Players.

If your particular set of rules mandates one Team per User then you should merge the two entities into a single table - which I would choose to call Managers, as that fits the domain better, but the decision is yours ;).

Comment: That is not really like that. To make it simple, each pool have his proper rules (like a touchdown count for 10 points).

6 users are part of the pool. Each of those 6 users choose 10 players in the league. Each of those 10 players make points by doing things, like a touchdown (10 points).

I want to divide it like 1 pool => all users part of the pool => all of their selections.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I would link it with a foreign key to both pools and users (by pool_id and user_id respectively).  A selection can only have one pool.  A selection can only have one user.

I might use a primary key on the selections table that looks like:   pool_id, user_id, selection_id so the 30th selection by user 123 in the pool 001 would be 001/123/30.

Would you normally go after the data by user or pool and user?  Would you really print all the users selections regardless of pool?  If so you might consider rearranging the primary key so that it is user_id, pool_id, and then selection_id.  This could make lookups by user_id alone faster since it will be able to go after the first part of the primary key index.

Comment: I go after the data by pool. Then I divide it by users that contains all the selections. In fact, I calculate the points of a pool by calculating each user. So I must have every selection of one user by pool and it continue until no user is left.

Comment: I think you should use pool_id/user_id/selection_id as your primary key then.  Or at least make it a unique index if for some reason you want to use a sequence as your primary key.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this. selection_ordinal_id is an integer value increments when users add selections from their own pools.

PS: If selection contains only players, then you don't need that selection_ordinal_id as PK. You can make player_id included in composite PK.

[image]